# Function without parentheses returns a weird output

Tags: javascript

Just asking to understand how it works:

```js
function say(something) {
  return something;
}
let name = `Reza`;

console.log(say `My name is`, name, '!');
```

It returns a very weird output. I think that `My name is` is a string within an array and everything else is just a string (correct me if I am wrong).

My Question is, what is the point of that and when would it make sense to use a function like that?

Also I would be glad if someone could tell me why `My name is ${name}` is not working (`name` returns as an empty string).

PS: I know that could use the function with parentheses and it would work but that's not my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why My name is ${name} is not working (name returns as an empty
>   string).

This is because you have to pull out the value of `My name is` from *the array of string values* and return it

Try this:

```js
function say(something) {
   var str0 = something[0]
   return str0;
}
let name = `Reza`;
console.log(say`My name is${name}`, name, '!');  // My name is Reza !
```

We will receive thing like this:

[image]

I would like to point out that the `${name}` does not mean anything at all, because inside the `tag function`, we didn't do anything with it.

This is the result after running your codes on the Chrome devtools:

[image]

Let's see how we can explain what is actually going on. Well then, what you're using is called `Tagged templates`:

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged templates. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values.

That's why we see an `array` in the result:

For instance, if we run this codes on Chrome devtools:

```
function say(something) {
    return something;
}
console.log(say`anything`);
```

On the console tab, we will receive this result:

[image]

For more information, you could read it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

As we can see, the weird `raw` property, according to [MDN - Raw strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Raw_strings), it is:

> The special raw property, available on the first function argument of tagged templates, allows you to access the raw strings as they were entered, without processing escape sequences.

For example:

```
function tag(strings) {
  console.log(strings.raw[0]);
}

tag`string text line 1 \n string text line 2`;
// logs "string text line 1 \n string text line 2" ,
// including the two characters '\' and 'n'
```

And you are using the console.log() method, according to [MDN-Console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) we have its signature:

**Syntax: Console.log()**

> console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
>
> console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);

**Parameters**

`obj1 ... objN`

> A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string representations of
>   each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and
>   output.

`msg`

> A JavaScript string containing zero or more substitution strings.

`subst1 ... substN`

> JavaScript objects with which to replace substitution strings within
>   msg. This gives you additional control over the format of the output.

In your case, you're passing multiple arguments into the Console.log() method, hence it will work as the document said here: [Outputting multiple objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console)

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Since when do you no longer need parenthesis when calling a function?

Comment: @0x499602D2 since es6 (tagged templates)

Answer (score 2):

`say` tag is missing the arguments to the placeholders in the template string:

```js
function shout(parts, name/*<--HERE*/) {
  return `${parts[0]}${name}${parts[1]}!!!`;
}

let name = `Reza`;
console.log(shout `My name is ${name}`);
```

`say` receives data from the template string as a split string around the placeholders:

```
[
  "My name is ",
  "!"
] Reza
```

Look at this example from the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

```
function myTag(strings, personExp, ageExp) {
  var str0 = strings[0]; // "That "
  var str1 = strings[1]; // " is a "

  var ageStr;
  if (ageExp > 99){
    ageStr = 'centenarian';
  } else {
    ageStr = 'youngster';
  }

  // We can even return a string built using a template literal
  return `${str0}${personExp}${str1}${ageStr}`;
}

var person = 'Mike';
var age = 28;
var output = myTag`That ${ person } is a ${ age }`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing `My name is ${name}` should work. Its because your passing `My name is` to the say function as a tagged template literal, which by default passes the arguments as an array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Close, the template parts are passed as an array while the template args are passed variadically.

Answer (score 2):

Your tagged template has a missing argument, it should include a strings array argument as first argument.

```
 function say(strings, something) { 
    return strings[0] + "Mr. " + something +"!"; 
} 

let name = `Reza`; 
console.log(say `My name is ${name}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple

```js
console.log `Hi there`;
```

> why My name is ${name} is not working (name returns as an empty string).

```
console.log(say `My name is`, name, '!'); /* I don't see `${name}` here */
```

Also, `name` was never passed as an argument to `say` function!

```js
function say(something) {
  return something;
}
let name = `Reza`;
/* say without () */
console.log(say `My name is ${name} !`);

/* say with () */
console.log(say(`My name is ${name} !`));
```

```js
let who = 'everyone';
console.log `Hello ${who}`; /* note, no -> () */
console.log(`Hello ${who}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent hours researching documents in order to answer your question. And I'll try my best to explain it simply.

My first answer is, in fact, a ***text explanation***. However, I remember [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) once said that:

> Examples are better than 1000 words. Examples are often easier to
>   understand than text explanations.

Well then, this answer supplements all explanations with clarifying "Try it Yourself" examples.

There are two concepts in Javascript that involved: the [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) and the [Console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) method.

I'll re-write your codes, breaking them into two parts,  like this: (the executed result remains the same).

```js
// part 1
function say(something) {
  return something;
}
let name = `Reza`;
let output = say`My name is`; 
// part 2
console.log(output, name, '!');
```

Let's see how these two parts related to the concepts of [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) and the [Console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) method, respectively.

First, examine this example:

### Example 1:

```js
function say(something) {
   return something;
}
let output = say`My name is`; 
console.log(output)
```

After running this example, we'll see an `array` that contains one element which is a `string`: "My name is"

This is the behavior of the [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates)

Before we actually dive into how [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) works, let's take a look at some examples below:

### Example 2:

```js
function say(something) {
   return something[0];
}
let output = say`My name is`; 
console.log(output)
```

After running the example 2, we'll receive a `string`: "My name is", instead of an `array` as the example 1 did.

Well then, what if I want to pass a `name` to it? see this:

### Example 3

```js
function say(something, name) {
   return `${something[0]}${name}`;
}
let name = 'Reza';
let output = say`My name is ${name}`; 
console.log(output)
```

Yay! It works as expected. Well then, what if I want to pass two arguments instead of one? see this:

### Example 4

```js
function say(something, name, age) {
    let str0 = something[0];
    let str1 = something[1];
    let str2 = something[2];
    return `${str0}${name}${str1}${age}${str2}`;
}
let name = 'Reza';
let age = 1000;
let output = say`My name is ${name}, I'm ${age} years old!`; 
console.log(output)
```

Quite clear, right? This is how we use [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates).

The examination of the [Tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates) is done now. Let's see how `Console.log()` method works.

### Example 5

```js
console.log(`My name is `)
```

We are all familiar with this usage of [Console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console) method, passing one argument. Well then, what if I want to pass multiple arguments to it. See this:

### Example 6

```js
let name = `Reza`;
console.log(`My name is `, name, '!')
```

It combined all together into one single output.

Well then, for now, let's go back to your sample:

```js
function say(something) {
  return something;  // the `something` is still an array
}
let name = `Reza`;

console.log(say `My name is`, name, '!');
// the console.log() method will try to combine all these three arguments
// into one single output
// this is why we got the output as an array with a string: "name" and a string: "!"
```

We could fix it like this:

### Example 7

```js
function say(something) {
   return something[0]; 
}
let name = `Reza`;
console.log(say`My name is`, name, '!');
```

Or like this:

### Example 8

```js
function say(something, name) {
   return `${something[0]}${name}`; 
}
let name = `Reza`;
console.log(say`My name is ${name} `, '!');
```

However, let's see this example:

### Example 9

```js
function say(something, name) {
  return `${something[0]}${name}`; 
}
let name = `Reza`;
console.log(say`My name is ${name} `, name, '!');
```

We'll receive `My name is Reza Reza !`. I believe that, for now, we all understand why we got it.